# where to declare constructor of class in visual studio 2010 winforms project c++?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio

I need to call methods of class by pressing buttons, but I don't want to create new object every time. Besides, class creates list, so I do not want to create list again.

Comment: Your description points towards **singleton**, but well they are inherently bad enough to not be adviced until we know the details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to make project with buttons. When I press first button - add element to list,second - delete element from list. But to make this I need to initialize object
`ArrayList *x=new ArrayList();`
but where I can do it?In console application I do it in main. But where I can do it in application with forms?

Comment: In the form class constructor.  Your project also has a Main() method, in the unlikely case you want to make it a global variable.

Comment: I see. It's where `//TODO: Add the constructor code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ArrayList will be used only inside the form class, make it a member of the class and initialize it in the form constructor:

```
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myList = gcnew ArrayList();
    }
protected:
    ArrayList^ myList;
```

As Konrad has pointed out, using [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sbxh9x2.aspx) is preferred over the use of ArrayList. Something like this:

```
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        x = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<String^>();
    }
private:
    System::Collections::Generic::List<String^>^ x;
```

Comment: Why would you ever use `ArrayList`? I see that the OP mentioned it but please don’t use it, not even for the purpose of demonstration.

Comment: ArrayList is my own class - linked list without pointers(with dynamic array). I don't use generics in C++.I prefer STL.